# How can we write code having loop, if/else and return statement using java streams

Tags: java

I need to use java streams for this piece of code.

```
for(int i =0 ;i< maxWaitTimeForRegistration ; i++) {
            if (service.getRefreshDeviceDetails(BaseTest.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnected")) {
                return true;
            }
            WaitinSeconds(5);
        }
```

I tried using this

```
IntStream.range(0, maxWaitTimeForRegistration).forEach(j -> {
           if (service.getRefreshDeviceDetails(BaseTest.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnected")) {
                return true;
            }
            WaitinSeconds(5);
        }
        });
```

But since forEach method is returning void, so It's not right.

Comment: Why do you need this in streams? It's an imperative kind of loop, not a functional one. Streams can possibly be used, but they are not the correct solution.

Comment: Unless this is a class assignment, why do you need to use streams?

Comment: Not a class assignment but client's request

Answer (score 1):

*Technically* it could be done this way:

```java
private static boolean retryStream() {
    return IntStream.range(0, MAX_WAIT_TIME_FOR_REGISTRATION)
            .peek(tryNum -> waitSeconds(4))
            .anyMatch(tryNum -> service.getRefreshDeviceDetails(BaseTest.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnected")));
}
```

But the Stream API is not really intended for blocking retries. Also, this way the stream is waiting even before the first check... so you would probably need to use another if condition check before the stream retry.

---

A working soution:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Scratch {

    private static final int     MAX_WAIT_TIME_FOR_REGISTRATION = 4;
    private static final Service service                        = new Service();
    private static String        BaseTest                       = "Test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // change the value asynchronously
        new Thread(() -> {
            waitSeconds(4 * 2);
            BaseTest = "Disconnected";
        }).start();

//      System.out.println(retry());
        System.out.println(retryStream());
    }

    private static boolean retry() {
        for(int i = 0; i< MAX_WAIT_TIME_FOR_REGISTRATION; i++) {
            if (service.getRefreshDeviceDetails(BaseTest.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnected"))) {
                return true;
            }
            waitSeconds(4);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean retryStream() {
        return IntStream.range(0, MAX_WAIT_TIME_FOR_REGISTRATION)
                .peek(tryNum -> waitSeconds(4))
                .anyMatch(tryNum -> service.getRefreshDeviceDetails(BaseTest.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnected")));
    }

    private static void waitSeconds(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}

class Service {

    public boolean getRefreshDeviceDetails(boolean disconnected) {
        return disconnected;
    }
}
```